# cookie on a data uri page

Tags: javascript, cookies, data-uri

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181831/does-a-data-uri-page-allow-writing-and-reading-a-cookie) about the same subject has given me 8 negative votes. I hope now to be clearer.
If you run

```
document.cookie ='ppkcookie1=testcookie;';alert(document.cookie);
```

on any web page the content of the cookie appears in the message box.
if you run the code above inside a very simple data-uri page (you could copy and paste the following string on the address bar in FF or Chrome, since IE does not support it)

```
 data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<h1>hi people</h1><script>document.cookie='ppkcookie1=testcookie;';alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

the message box is empty

Does this mean that cookies cannot be used on data-uri pages or there is some errors in my piece of code?

Comment: If I paste this into the address bar in chrome - preceded by `javascript: ` - it alerts just fine. `javascript: document.cookie ='ppkcookie1=testcookie;';alert(document.cookie);`. What are you expecting and what are you seeing?

Comment: Paste the following string, which complies data uri scheme: `data:text/html,<h1>hi people</h1><script>document.cookie='ppkcookie1=testcookie;';alert(document.cookie);</script>`

Comment: Chrome result: "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are data URIs on <img>s XSS exploitable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228771/are-data-uris-on-imgs-xss-exploitable)